# How to Adjust Background of ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am wondering how to change and adjust the background of a ListBox, not of a ListBoxItem. I would like the background to be PhoneChromeBrush with an opacity of .5. The ListBox is actually overlayed partially on a picture, and so the effect I'm trying to accomplish is that where the ListBox overlays the image, I would like the user to still be able to see the item through the ListBox but with a tinted effect, while the items in the ListBox are 100% opaque (opacity=1.0). I am not sure how to change the ListBox's background in this way while keeping the items completely solid and visible.

EDIT

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="105"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="ViewportContainer">
            <Image x:Name="Viewport" LayoutUpdated="Viewport_LayoutUpdated" 
                           Source="{Binding}"
                   toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"/>
        </Grid>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="ListBox" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                         Visibility="Collapsed" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="1,0,0,0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="100" Height="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have ListBoxItems with a solid background, but the ListBox itself be translucid, try setting the background of the ListBox in this way. Children controls won't inherit the opacity.

```
<ListBox>
     <ListBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </ListBox.Background>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem Background="Red" Margin="10">Item</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That actually makes everything in the ListBox opaque as well.

Comment: Do you mean that what should be semi-transparent is the area outside of ListBoxItem's, but inside the ListBox? I understood your question as the whole control should be 50% transparent.

Comment: Well, id like the items to remain 100% visible, but behind the items I can see right through the ListBox, so I'd like to make the backround of the ListBox 50% transparent with a grey color, so it looks like where the ListBox overlays the image it is slightly tinted

Comment: I edited my answer for what I think you mean. If that's still not it, could you provide an image of the desired effect? Or maybe someone else can answer it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Phone's **`background`** color (**`light`** / **`dark`**) not the **`accent`** color (cyan, red, nokia blue, yellow bla bla) its simple to find. You need to put these attributes into `ListBox` tag in your **xaml**-

```
Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0.5"
```

This will set Phone's background color to your `listbox`, either **dark** or **light**.

If you want your `listbox`'s background to be Phone's **accent** color, you can get it by **code**-

```
Color AccentColor = (System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
```

This will return Phone's current **accent** color. Now you want **opacity** of 0.5. To do that you can do,

```
AccentColor.A = (byte) 127;
```

`A` is for **alpha** / **opacity** and ranges from 0 to 255 (byte). All the **ARGB** values are already assigned, only you need to change the **opacity** (`A`) value as per you requirement.

Now you can put this `AccentColor` as `Brush`. To change the `listbox`'s background,

`myListBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(AccentColor);`

The problem I got is, to listbox's background returns **`Brush`** not **`Color`** so

when you say **`{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}`** it internally takes it as,

```
myListBox.Background = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"];
```

this is not in case when you want to put **accent** color as
**background**, because
**`{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}`** or **`Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]`** returns **`color`** and we are assigning color to a Brush (listbox's background)! That's why when you set listbox's background as accent color like **`{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}`** it'll crash application. Till now I don't know how to put accent color via xaml code. Sorry for that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I've noticed the same issues you describe above as well. The problem I am having currently is that when setting the background opacity, the items in the ListBox become opaque as well. I really only want the background of the ListBox to be an opaque brush while the items should be normal (A=255). I am not sure how to set this in the XAML, because when setting background opacity the ListBoxItems become opaque as well.

Comment: In your case, are you talking about "image" which are list items to be normal ?? I mean which stack panel you're talking about (in you xaml) ? To make an item normal, put attribute **`Opacity="1"`** in your desired **`StackPanel`** tag. Let me know in case of any query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the template of the listbox which you are using, there is an incredibly easy way to do that 
Locate the listbox you want the template of in the designer 
right click on the ListBox in the menu goto EditTemplate>Edit A Copy
this will generate a copy of the currently used template in the resources of the page